# How to print to Zebra GK420d label printer using ZPL passthrough mode from internet explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, zpl

Is there a way to print out a simple pass through ZPL command in IE9?

I use Windows 7 IE8 x86 with the latest Zdesigner driver (v2.6.63.12) but now preparing the tansition to IE9 and a very basic feature of my web app is failing.

The pass through set in the printer driver properties.

I have a static HTML file containing only the below 1 line:
${^XA^BY3^FO140,150^BCN,100,N,N,N,A^FDJVGL0632341422706201^FS^XZ}$

In IE8 i just click on print and it prints a nice barcode to my only/default bar code printer, but not in IE9.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you point the driver to a file output and look at the output? Maybe IE9 is mangling the output?

Comment: I get a complete garbage:

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW799
^LL1598
^LS0
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

This looks ZPL, but i dont see how it derives to my above string.

Comment: The code above is the initialization string from the driver which sets up the printer before printing a job. It looks like the driver is not set to pass thru mode, if it were, it shouldn't send the init string. Check you driver settings and make sure the passthru mode is enabled for the driver you are using and that ${ and }$ are the bookends for it

Comment: I have confirmed that ZPL passthrough is configured in the driver in both the user and printing defaults area. Then i have opened NOTEPAD, where the same ZPL string prints just fine when encapsulated into ${...zpl...}$ So the driver is unable to lock on to the ZPL if it comes from IE9.

Answer (score 3):

Zebra has recommended to change the passthrough strings to

`%( )%` instead of the default.

In some cases it is also wise to add to the beginning of individual ZPL lines
`"^FX "` - being ^FX and a space, without the double quotes.

With these adjustments printing ZPL passthrough from IE9 using the Zdesigner driver is working.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and resolved in these steps:

1. on the i.e.9 machine, install the microsoft 438168_intl_x64_zip.exe patch
2. plug in the zebra printer (we had a GK420t) and let the drivers install
3. go to printer preferences and, in the advanced setup tab, check "Enable Passthrough Mode"
4. set up a new printer as generic/text, replacing the current drivers and setting it as the default printer.
5. on the web page, put this in the header:

   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">

which forces ie7 compatibility

We were able to get printing to work at that point.

The patch can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2584449